# How Do I read the Database?

Tags: php, mysql, model-view-controller

This is the config.php file under the core

```
<?php

define("WEBSITE_TITLE", 'MY SHOP');

//database details
define('DB_NAME', "eshop_db");
define('DB_USER', "root");
define('DB_PASS', "");
define('DB_TYPE', "mysql");
define('DB_HOST', "localhost");


define('THEME','eshop/');
define('DEBUG', true);
if(DEBUG){
    ini_set('display_errors', 1);
}else{
    ini_set('display_errors', 0);
}
?>
```

Here I define my database name as eshop_db and the rest of the data

This is my database.php file under the core folder

```
<?php 

Class Database{
    public static $con;
    public function __construct()
    {
        try{
 
            $string = DB_TYPE . ":host=".DB_HOST . ";dbname=" . DB_NAME;
            self::$con = new PDO($string,DB_USER,DB_PASS);

        }catch (PDOException $e){

             die($e->getMessage());
        }
    }

    public static function getInstence(){
        if(self::$con){
            return self::$con;
        }
        return $instance = new self();
        // return self::$con;
    }

        //read function 
    public function read($query,$data = array()){
        $stm = self::$con->prepare($query);
        $result = $stm->execute();
        if($result){
            $data = $stm->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
            if(is_array($data)){

                return $data;

            }
        }
            return false;
    }


    public function write($query,$data = array()){

    }
   
}

$db = Database::getInstence();
$data = $db->read("discribe users");
show($data);
```

In my database file, I first created a class and created the database connection also checked the database connection. The connection seems to be working but when I try to read the "users" table in the database it's not showing anything and no errors in the file too.

This is the first time I use PDO. I am using xampp. Do I need to install anything before using PDO? Could you please help me to solve this problem.

Comment: I assume $data is false, because your SQL query is invalid ('describe', not "discribe').

Comment: @NevilleKuyt Ohh what a silly mistake Thank You so much. Corrected as describe its working now.

Comment: Just a note: You are using MVC. So, instead of using a lot of _try-catch_ blocks inside classes, functions, etc, you could use ONLY ONE _try-catch_ block at the entry point of your application (probably `index.php`). Like this: `try{ /* ...Create and use class instances of your app... */ } catch (\Throwable $throwable) { /* ...Present the _Error_ or _Exception_ object thrown either automatically by the system, or by you, the developer, via a _throw_ statement, to the user... */ }`.

Comment: Or (recommended) you could define error handling functions, to be used by `set_error_handler`, `set_exception_handler` and `register_shutdown_function`. For more details in regard of error handling in MVC-based applications I strongly recommend you to read [this tutorial](https://phpdelusions.net/articles/error_reporting). I also strongly recommend you [this tutorial](https://phpdelusions.net/pdo) in regard of PDO.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$db = Database::getInstence();
$data = $db->read("describe users");
show($data);
```

Thanks to @NevilleKuy it Must be "describe" Previously it was "discribe"